# How can I save a VBScript array to Javascript array?

Tags: javascript, arrays, vbscript, asp-classic

How to take a VBScript array and saving to a Javascript Array, in the client side?
Pretty much what I'm trying to do is to get table data get a random row and put in html input,
then onclick it will get another random row, but I'm a little confused on how update the inputs with the new random row, this is how my VBScript code is looking like:

```
If Not rs.EOF Then
   questions = rs.GetRows(total,0)
   If IsArray(questions) Then
      max = total - 1
      min = 0
      Randomize
      n = Int( (max - min + 1 ) * Rnd + min)
```

This is how my input looks like:

```
<input id="option" onclick="??" value="<% Response.Write(questions(2,n)) %>">
```

Is there a better way of doing things? Because my idea is to get the entire `questions` array and store in javascript so it's easier to update the fields using DOM.
Can anyone help me?

Comment: How about `<script>window.yourArray = [template code here]</script>`?

Comment: How will you display your array?

Comment: @parchment Can you explain how that works?

Comment: @glenatron How I will display my array, how do you mean?

Comment: @FranciscoCosta I'm actually unfamiliar with asp... Hopefully someone else more knowledgeable will turn that to a real answer.

Comment: Thanks anyway for trying.

Comment: I'm really asking what you want to do with it, as that will indicate the best way to find it, but I'll put together a quick answer to explain what you are looking for.

Comment: @glenatron what I want to do is to get the db table data (all) into an array (that I have done in VBScript), get random row and show the several row fields in several inputs and then on button click, get another random row and show in the several inputs, like the last row, everything without reloading the entire page.

Comment: @glenatron I really thank you for trying to help me!

Comment: Depending on how important the data is - so if it's a quiz for fun it doesn't matter, if it's an exam for students it does - you might find it easier to load in all the questions using JavaScript and then choose random ones in the browser.

Comment: Well that was my idea in the first place, but I was not able to configure the iis to run javascript with asp, do you know where can I find a tutorial or something to help run javascript along with asp

Comment: The best way of going would be not to use vbscript...

Comment: @JanDvorak how can I do that? I've been trying to create a connection using javascript in asp tag without any luck, can you help on this one?

Answer (score 0):

If you want something to be accessible from any javascript in your page, just declare it as a global variable early on. If you want to be a bit more correct you could wrap that up in a function but it doesn't matter greatly- the output you want is the same.

Basic array notation in JavaScript is values ( either numbers, strings or objects ) wrapped in square brackets. To declare a JavaScript variable available for your page you might just say this:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
   var myArray= [ 'item one', 'item two', 'item three' ];
</script>
```

Then anywhere you call `myArray` in that page, you will be able access it.

To combine that with your vbscript, you just need to format your array as a JavaScript literal and write it into the page. Now my vbscript is very rusty ( as it *should be* unless I have fallen through a timewarp and it is still 2001 - every available web development language is better than vbscript ) but I think the notation would be something like this, assuming your questions variable contains the array displayed in the right order:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
   var myArray= [ '<%= join( questions, "', '" ) %>' ];
</script>
```

Notice that I have to put quotes before and after my joined array to ensure they are correctly enclosed in quotes. You could also use double quotes but I seem to recall escaping double quotes in a vbscript string is *really* horrible.

Comment: Thanks I will try it, well I'm using iis that's why I'm using vbscript, can't configure the iis to run javascript with asp

Comment: Even on an old version IIS you should be able to run Asp.net or install PHP - even PHP is way better than old ASP and VBScript.

Comment: I'm using IIS 8 on windows 8

Comment: it seems this doesn't work, it gives me a 500 Internal Server Error, using this
`var myArray= [ '<%=response.write( join( questions, "', '" ) %>' ];`

Comment: IIS 8? Definitely don't use VBScript then. Every other option you could use is better. I think I missed a bracket in my code there. Also `<%=` is the same as `<% response.write` which was probably your problem.

Comment: Right now I'm trying to go only with javascript, making a test page only to create a connection and display/update de fields, and then passing the right code to the page I'm doing, but no luck on creating the db connection, I change the scriptLanguage in IIS to **JScript**.

Comment: The language used here won't make a huge difference- you need to understand what is happening and why and I don't think you have a good handle on how JavaScript works in the browser. This task will go faster if you take the time learn the basics of JavaScript then come back to the job in hand. Try creating an HTML page with a predetermined list of questions and doing all the front-end JavaScript, then once that works, figure out how to do the back-end scripting.

Comment: That's exactly what I thought and is exactly what I've been doing the last hours, totally left aside the asp and vbscript, and only used javascript.